# How to run shake and fadeout method at the same time on an image? (JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have added a shaking effect inside the `fadeOut()` method. The fadeout effect is working fine, but the image does not shake.

I tried the shaking effect outside the fadeout method and it is working fine. Note that I have declared the jQueryUI library in my HTML.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $('#middle').fadeOut(3000, function() {
    $("#middle").effect("shake", {
      times: 4
    }, 900);
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```